# Cannot convert from int to Project.Models.ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-roles

The below code gets me the error.

```
 _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(_userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName).Id, "Employee");
```

I have included the code for further reference. I am trying to create a new user everytime the site is accessed and add a default role. User is properly added. Also I have previously seeded the roles, so roles exist.

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
  {
    private readonly MainContext _context;
    private readonly OtherContext _orcontext;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _appenv;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
  }
    public ItemsController(MainContext context, OtherContext _orcontext, IHostingEnvironment appEnvironment, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _orcontext= orcontext;
        _appenv = appEnvironment;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    // GET: Items
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var uname = User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 5);
        if ((await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(uname)) == null)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = uname
            };

            IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
            _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(_userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName).Id, "Employee");

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `AddToRoleAsync` is a user *instance*, not an id. Hence the error. In other words, remove the `.Id` bit.

```
_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(_userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName), "Employee");
```

Comment: Including .UserName didn't work for me. I ended up using (user, "Employee");
Probably because my method is rather hacky, using windows authentication and the using SignInManager to sign in via Identity to get the roles.
Thanks for the help @Chris